# Meteor (mup and Galaxy) - Update to settings.json only

Tags: meteor, mup, meteor-galaxy

Do you have to do a full deploy with mup or Galaxy if only `settings.json` is changing?

Comment: Yes you have to

Answer (score 0):

If you'd open your Galaxy portal, choose your app, then click on "Settings" tab and scroll down to your "Meteor Settings", then underneath it there will be:

> To define custom settings, **redeploy** this app with the `--settings` option: ...